# integrate authorize.net simple checkout with magento

Tags: magento, payment-gateway, authorize.net

I want to integrate authorize.net simple checkout ( http://developer.authorize.net/api/simplecheckout/ ) with magento.

My requirement is that the user should be redirected to authorize.net site to make payment from magento one page checkout and after successful payment user should be redirected to magento success page.

Comment: Did you tried this http://magebase.com/magento-tutorials/how-to-setup-magento-for-authorize-net-direct-post-method/ ?

Comment: Hello, thank you for your comment. i checked this method but in this method also it is asking to enter credit card details on magento site itself, i donot want credit card details to be entered on my site, user should be taken to the authorize.net site for payment.